How to find the average and SE of a un unknown PDF from a set on sample values already combined into several bins?
I have this data here:

and I want to know the average and the SE of the original PDF that generated it. As a first estimate I'm assuming its normally distributed.
Can you help me?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have a look at this question, though you'll likely have to assume that the bottom and top bin have a finite (or even identical) size.

@PBulls That assumption is unnecessary.  The solution I posted in that thread is appropriate even for unbounded bins (and is one of the few good ways to deal with them).

Here is a very approximate solution.
First, take a guess at the median. Looks like it's about 280, but that's just eyeballing it. You could calculate it assuming a uniform distribution within the second highest bin, but you could do better by trying to make each bin closer to what would happen under normality. Then assume that median = mean (which it does in a normal distribution). Then you can play with different standard deviations until you get something close to what you want.
